# Android: inverted color on dark mode

Tags: android, android-darkmode

I have troubles with some imageview on certain Android phones.

It seems that the dark mode invert the color of certains assets (not all, it seems only black/dark gray ones)

An example.

[image: Image on light/normal mode (correct)]

[image: Image on dark mode]

I cannot find a way to avoid this. Is there some kind of properties that protect the image from being inverted?

Comment: Can you implement some source code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you can use
[setForceDarkAllowed(false)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View#setForceDarkAllowed(boolean))
if you just want to apply this to one View.

Or you can change the attributes/colors in your res/values-night folder, which holds all colors that are used in case the dark mode is activated.

Answer (score 2):

You can disable Dark mode on your app by using:

```
AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO)
```

If you want to disable it on a view, you can

1. Use light style for a specific view
2. Use `android:forceDarkAllowed="false"`